# Property 'play' does not exist on type 'Element' in React SyntheticEvent

Tags: reactjs, typescript, dom, html5-video

I have an onClick event attached to a button, when it gets triggered, I need to get the nextElementSibling *(which is a video element)* of the button, then need to call the play method.
Below is the onClick handler -

```
const handleVideoEvent = (e: SyntheticEvent<HTMLButtonElement>) => {
        e.currentTarget.parentElement.nextElementSibling.play();
}
```

Now, I know the typescript compiler doesn't know about type of sibling element, so to let it know I have tried using below code instead -

```
const handleVideoEvent = (e: SyntheticEvent<HTMLButtonElement>) => {
            const videoElement: HTMLVideoElement = e.currentTarget.parentElement.previousElementSibling;
            videoElement.play();
 }
```

But this shows another error on videoElement declaration, which is -

> Type 'Element' is missing the following properties from type
> 'HTMLVideoElement': height, playsInline, poster, videoHeight, and 158
> more.

I am new to typescript, any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since there isn't a way for typescript to tell at compile time that this is safe, you will need to use a [type assertion](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#type-assertions).

```
const handleVideoEvent = (e: SyntheticEvent<HTMLButtonElement>) => {
   (e.currentTarget.parentElement.nextElementSibling as HTMLVideoElement).play();
}

// or:
const handleVideoEvent = (e: SyntheticEvent<HTMLButtonElement>) => {
   const videoElement = e.currentTarget.parentElement.nextElementSibling as HTMLVideoElement;
   videoElement.play();
}
```

This tells typescript "I know it looks like this isn't an HTMLVideoElement, but trust me, it is". Be aware that by doing so you are telling typescript not to check your work. If it turns out to not be a video element, typescript cannot point this out and you may get an exception at runtime.

Another option if you want to keep the type safety is to add code to verify that it's a video element. This may be an unnecessary check from your point of view:

```
const handleVideoEvent = (e: SyntheticEvent<HTMLButtonElement>) => {
   const element = e.currentTarget.parentElement.nextElementSibling;
   if (element instanceof HTMLVideoElement) {
     // Inside this if statement, typescript knows it must be a video element
     element.play();
   } else {
     console.error('uh oh');
   }
}
```